# Vertical alignment of atoms in chemfig

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

I have a problem aligning atoms in `chemfig` when one of the atoms has a descender. The solution proposed in the manual is not really good, because it changes the position of bonds. Consider the test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\chemfig{A-X-M} \chemfig{A-X-Mg}}

\fbox{\chemfig{A-X-M} \chemfig{{A\strut}-{X\strut}-Mg}}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

In the top row, the second formula has `Mg` too high. When adding the `\strut` (or `\vphantom`) to the other atoms, the bond lines are then too low, which is especially bad if you are displaying different formulas side by side, as in the example.

Is there any way I can move the `Mg` label down or make the descender invisible to `\chemfig`?

Comment: This is addressed in part III section 4 _Vertical alignment_ of the [`chemfig` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chemfig).

Comment: @cgnieder And the suggested workaround is exactly what I described, and I don't find the solution entirely satisfactory. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Maybe `\chemfig{A-X-\smash{\printatom{Mg}}}`?

Comment: @cgnieder That seems to do it. I just need to manually offset any bond arriving at the bottom of `Mg`, but I don't mind doing that in my current document.

Comment: @cgnieder Possibly better `\smash[b]{\printatom{Mg}}` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: M\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{g}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\smash` or (maybe even better) `amsmath`'s `\smash[b]` can help here `\chemfig{A-X-\smash[b]{\printatom{Mg}}}`. For the sake of not having to type `\smash` *and* `\printatom` I define a `\smashatom` below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\smashatom[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \smash{\printatom{#2}}%
  \else
    \smash[#1]{\printatom{#2}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\chemfig{A-X-M} \chemfig{A-X-Mg}}

\fbox{\chemfig{A-X-M} \chemfig{{A\strut}-{X\strut}-Mg}}

\fbox{\chemfig{A-X-M} \chemfig{A-X-\smashatom[b]{Mg}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]